# Two players take turns placing a domino onto a $6\times6$ grid. The first player who can't place a domino loses.

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-game-theory

Two powerhouses of history go head to head.
Leonhard Euler starts. Carl Friedrich Gauss plays second.
They have a $6\times 6$ grid. Each turn a player places a domino (a $1\times2$ or $2\times1$ rectangle). Dominoes cannot overlap, and the first player who can’t place a domino loses.

We will assume they are both perfectly intelligent (trivial result) and know the best strategy. Who wins?

Generalisation to $n\times n$ grid?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: This is the game of [Cram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram_(game)) and for the normal game there are simple symmetry strategies when at least one side of the board is even.

Comment: This seems like it belongs at puzzling.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Since Gauss is smart, he would probably figure this out:

Let the points with integer coordinates be the vertices of the grid, with the origin corresponding to the center. Gauss should use this strategy from the start of the game: If Euler places a domino centered at coordinates $(x,y)$, Gauss should play at coordinates $(-x,-y)$. If such a move was not allowed, then Euler's move would not have been allowed either. Therefore, Gauss makes the last move and wins. For the second question, if $n$ is even, then Gauss can use the same strategy and win. I don't know the solution when $n$ is odd.